# how to remove mandatory required fields in buddypress registration

Tags: buddypress, user-registration, hacks

i have installed buddypress 1.5.1, wp 3.2.1. the registration field shows 5 mandatory fields to be filled, i need to limit this to 3, my site needs username, email, password( just like in tumblr ), how to remove these mandatory registration fields in buddypress registration.
Is their any snippet/plugin to accomplish that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i did find an hack for this problem

Make the field fullname, confirm password as display:none

Bind the data from username to fullname and from password to confirm password

For eg ( a simple binding example )

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#target').bind('keyup keypress blur', function()
 {
    $('#target1').val($(this).val());
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="target">Type Something:</label>
    <input id="target" type="text" />
<input id="target1" type="text" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Do the above for your criteria
I dont know whether its a perfect solution, but this solves my problem.

Comment: Where did you insert this code? In functions.php or bp-custom.php?